# SQL error #1064 on CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am importing a database from MySQL 4.0.27-standard into a new webhost with Server version: 5.5.48-37.8 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 37.8, Revision 727, using PHPMySQL.

I am getting the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL '',   PRIMARY KEY  (site_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM' at
>   line 14

Here is the CREATE TABLE query:

```
CREATE TABLE Brewing (
  site_id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  site_url varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  site_name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  site_comment varchar(255) default NULL,
  site_rating int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  site_entrydate varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  site_lasttouched timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (site_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: thank you, removing the (14) after timestamp worked

Comment: I believe it is `5.6.4` and above for fractionals.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the size of `timestamp`. It already has a default for setting up timestamp. So remove (14).
Plus added bonus, add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for auto update of `timestamp`.

Answer (score 2):

The length argument for `timestamp` represents fractional seconds (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)).  The allowed lengths for fractional seconds are 0 to 6.  14 is too long.

I would advise you to just remove the length altogether.